# What is the error in this vhdl code to generate noisy sine wave signal?

Tags: vhdl

We are designing  a vhdl code where we are designing sine waves to which noise will be added. Why is this this code showing error...We are integrating three codes together, which has been provided here

The code that we have designed:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Unsigned.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;


entity freq_div is

     generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
    Port (clk_p, clk_n , rst, up, pause : in  STD_LOGIC;

         seconds : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         minutes : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         hours : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

        random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0); 
        data_outa,data_outb,data_outc,data_outd : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

           count : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0));
end freq_div;

architecture Behavioral of freq_div is

signal sec,min,hour : integer range 0 to 60 :=0;
signal counta : integer :=1;
signal clka : std_logic :='0';

signal clk2: std_logic;
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal clk: std_logic_vector(28 downto 0):=(others=>'0');

signal data_out1,rand_temp1,noisy_signal,data_outb1,data_outc1,data_outd1, summation_signal : integer;
signal noisy_signal1,s1,s2,s3,s4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal summation_signal1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
signal i : integer :=0;
signal j : integer :=120;
signal k : integer :=40;
signal l : integer :=80;
signal ii,iii: integer :=0 ;
signal jj: integer :=30 ;
signal kk: integer :=60 ;
signal ll: integer :=90 ;
signal ii_gate: std_logic := '0';

type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal sine2 : memory_type;
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"06",
x"06",x"07",x"07",x"08",x"08",x"09",x"09",x"0a",x"0a",x"0b",
x"0b",x"0c",x"0c",x"0d",x"0d",x"0e",x"0e",x"0f",x"0f",x"10",
x"11",x"11",x"12",x"13",x"13",x"14",x"15",x"15",x"16",x"17",
x"18",x"18",x"19",x"1a",x"1b",x"1b",x"1c",x"1d",x"1e",x"1e",
x"1f",x"20",x"21",x"22",x"23",x"23",x"24",x"25",x"26",x"27",
x"28",x"29",x"2a",x"2b",x"2c",x"2d",x"2f",x"2f",x"30",x"31",
x"32",x"34",x"35",x"35",x"36",x"37",x"38",x"39",x"3a",x"3b",
x"3c",x"3c",x"3e",x"3f",x"40",x"41",x"42",x"43",x"44",x"45",
x"46",x"46",x"47",x"48",x"49",x"49",x"4a",x"4b",x"4c",x"4c",
x"4e",x"4f",x"4f",x"50",x"51",x"51",x"52",x"53",x"53",x"54",
x"55",x"55",x"56",x"57",x"57",x"58",x"58",x"59",x"59",x"5a",
x"5a",x"5b",x"5b",x"5c",x"5c",x"5d",x"5d",x"5e",x"5e",x"5f",
x"5f",x"5f",x"60",x"60",x"60",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"62",
x"62",x"62",x"62",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",
x"63",x"63",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"60",
x"60",x"60",x"5f",x"5f",x"5f",x"5e",x"5e",x"5d",x"5d",x"5c",
x"5c",x"5b",x"5b",x"5a",x"5a",x"59",x"59",x"58",x"58",x"57",
x"57",x"56",x"55",x"55",x"54",x"54",x"53",x"53",x"52",x"51",
x"51",x"50",x"4f",x"4f",x"4e",x"4d",x"4c",x"4c",x"4b",x"4a",
x"49",x"49",x"48",x"47",x"46",x"46",x"45",x"44",x"44",x"43",
x"42",x"41",x"41",x"40",x"3f",x"3e",x"3d",x"3c",x"3c",x"3b",
x"3a",x"39",x"38",x"37",x"36",x"35",x"35",x"34",x"33",x"32",
x"31",x"30",x"2f",x"2f",x"2e",x"2d",x"2c",x"2b",x"2a",x"29",
x"28",x"28",x"27",x"26",x"25",x"24",x"23",x"23",x"22",x"21",
x"20",x"1f",x"1e",x"1e",x"1d",x"1c",x"1b",x"1b",x"1a",x"19",
x"18",x"18",x"17",x"16",x"15",x"15",x"14",x"13",x"13",x"12",
x"11",x"11",x"10",x"0f",x"0f",x"0e",x"0d",x"0d",x"0c",x"0c",
x"0b",x"0b",x"0a",x"0a",x"09",x"09",x"08",x"08",x"07",x"07",
x"06",x"06",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00");


COMPONENT ila_1

PORT (  clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    probe0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT  ;

 begin

 seconds <= conv_std_logic_vector(sec,6);
 minutes <= conv_std_logic_vector(min,6);
 hours <= conv_std_logic_vector(hour,5);

   IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
  generic map (
     DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
     IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
  port map (
     O => clk2,  -- Buffer output
     I => clk_p,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
     IB => clk_n -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
  );

 process(clk2)
  begin
  if(clk2'event and clk2='1') then
  counta <=counta+1;
  if(counta = 5) then
  clka <= not clka;
  counta <=1;
  end if;
  end if;
  end process;

  process(clka)   --period of clk is 1 second.
  variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
  variable temp : std_logic := '0';
  begin

  if(clka'event and clka='1') then

  temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
  rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
  rand_temp(0) := temp;

  i <= i+ 1;
  if(i = 359) then
  i <= 0;
  end if;

  j <= j+ 1;
  if(j = 359) then
  j <= 0;
  end if;

  k <= k+ 1;
  if(k = 359) then
  k <= 0;
  end if;

  l <= l+ 1;
  if(l = 359) then
  l <= 0;
  end if;

  data_outa <= sine(i);

  data_outb <= sine(j);
  data_outc <= sine(k);
  data_outd <= sine(l);

  data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
  random_num <= rand_temp;
  rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
  noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
  noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));

 sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
       ii <= ii+ 1;
           if(ii = 359) then
           ii <=0;
           ii_gate <= '1';
           end if;

       if ii_gate = '1' then     
       s1 <= sine2(iii);
       iii <= iii+ 1;
       if(iii = 359) then
       iii <= 0;
       end if;

      s2 <= sine2(jj);
      jj <= jj+ 1;
      if(jj = 359) then
     jj <= 0;
      end if;
       s3 <= sine2(kk);
       kk <= kk+ 1;
       if(kk = 359) then
       kk <= 0;
       end if;
       s4 <= sine2(ll);
       ll <= ll+ 1;
       if(ll = 359) then
       ll <= 0;
       end if;

       end if;

  sec <= sec+ 1;
  if(sec = 59) then
  sec<=0;
  min <= min + 1;
  if(min = 59) then
  hour <= hour + 1;
  min <= 0;
  if(hour = 23) then
  hour <= 0;
  end if;
  end if;
  end if;
  end if;

  end process;


--    process(clk2, rst)
--        begin
--            if (rst = '1')then
--                clk <= (others=>'0');
--            elsif (clk2'event and clk2 = '1')then
--                clk <= clk + 1;
--            end if;
--    end process;


--  process(clk(25), rst,up,pause) 
--      begin
--      if (rst = '1') then
--          cnt <= (others=>'0');
--      elsif (clk(25) = '1' and clk(25)'event) then
--          if (up = '1' and pause = '0')then
--              cnt <= cnt + '1';
--          elsif (up = '0' and pause = '0') then
--              cnt <= cnt - '1';
--          elsif( pause ='1')then
--              cnt <= cnt;
--          end if;
--      end if;
--  end process;

--  count <= cnt;






end Behavioral;
```

1st code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sine_wave is
 generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
port (clk :in  std_logic;
      random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0); 
      data_outa,data_outb,data_outc,data_outd : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
      );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is
signal data_out1,rand_temp1,noisy_signal,data_outb1,data_outc1,data_outd1, summation_signal : integer;
signal noisy_signal1,s1,s2,s3,s4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal summation_signal1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
signal i : integer :=0;
signal j : integer :=120;
signal k : integer :=40;
signal l : integer :=80;
signal ii,iii: integer :=0 ;
signal jj: integer :=30 ;
signal kk: integer :=60 ;
signal ll: integer :=90 ;
signal ii_gate: std_logic := '0';
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal sine2 : memory_type;
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"06",
x"06",x"07",x"07",x"08",x"08",x"09",x"09",x"0a",x"0a",x"0b",
x"0b",x"0c",x"0c",x"0d",x"0d",x"0e",x"0e",x"0f",x"0f",x"10",
x"11",x"11",x"12",x"13",x"13",x"14",x"15",x"15",x"16",x"17",
x"18",x"18",x"19",x"1a",x"1b",x"1b",x"1c",x"1d",x"1e",x"1e",
x"1f",x"20",x"21",x"22",x"23",x"23",x"24",x"25",x"26",x"27",
x"28",x"29",x"2a",x"2b",x"2c",x"2d",x"2f",x"2f",x"30",x"31",
x"32",x"34",x"35",x"35",x"36",x"37",x"38",x"39",x"3a",x"3b",
x"3c",x"3c",x"3e",x"3f",x"40",x"41",x"42",x"43",x"44",x"45",
x"46",x"46",x"47",x"48",x"49",x"49",x"4a",x"4b",x"4c",x"4c",
x"4e",x"4f",x"4f",x"50",x"51",x"51",x"52",x"53",x"53",x"54",
x"55",x"55",x"56",x"57",x"57",x"58",x"58",x"59",x"59",x"5a",
x"5a",x"5b",x"5b",x"5c",x"5c",x"5d",x"5d",x"5e",x"5e",x"5f",
x"5f",x"5f",x"60",x"60",x"60",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"62",
x"62",x"62",x"62",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",
x"63",x"63",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"60",
x"60",x"60",x"5f",x"5f",x"5f",x"5e",x"5e",x"5d",x"5d",x"5c",
x"5c",x"5b",x"5b",x"5a",x"5a",x"59",x"59",x"58",x"58",x"57",
x"57",x"56",x"55",x"55",x"54",x"54",x"53",x"53",x"52",x"51",
x"51",x"50",x"4f",x"4f",x"4e",x"4d",x"4c",x"4c",x"4b",x"4a",
x"49",x"49",x"48",x"47",x"46",x"46",x"45",x"44",x"44",x"43",
x"42",x"41",x"41",x"40",x"3f",x"3e",x"3d",x"3c",x"3c",x"3b",
x"3a",x"39",x"38",x"37",x"36",x"35",x"35",x"34",x"33",x"32",
x"31",x"30",x"2f",x"2f",x"2e",x"2d",x"2c",x"2b",x"2a",x"29",
x"28",x"28",x"27",x"26",x"25",x"24",x"23",x"23",x"22",x"21",
x"20",x"1f",x"1e",x"1e",x"1d",x"1c",x"1b",x"1b",x"1a",x"19",
x"18",x"18",x"17",x"16",x"15",x"15",x"14",x"13",x"13",x"12",
x"11",x"11",x"10",x"0f",x"0f",x"0e",x"0d",x"0d",x"0c",x"0c",
x"0b",x"0b",x"0a",x"0a",x"09",x"09",x"08",x"08",x"07",x"07",
x"06",x"06",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00");
--hi
begin

process(clk)
variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
variable temp : std_logic := '0';
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then  

temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
rand_temp(0) := temp;

--data_out <= sine(i);
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 359) then
i <= 0;
end if;

j <= j+ 1;
if(j = 359) then
j <= 0;
end if;

k <= k+ 1;
if(k = 359) then
k <= 0;
end if;

l <= l+ 1;
if(l = 359) then
l <= 0;
end if;

data_outa <= sine(i);

data_outb <= sine(j);
data_outc <= sine(k);
data_outd <= sine(l);

data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
random_num <= rand_temp;
rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));
--data_outb1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(j)));
--data_outc1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(k)));
--data_outd1 <= to_integer(unsigned(sine(l)));
--summation_signal <= data_outb1+data_outc1+data_outd1+noisy_signal;
--summation_signal1 <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(summation_signal,12));

--for ii in 0 to 359 loop
--   sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
--   s1 <= sine2(ii);   
--  end loop;


   sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
     ii <= ii+ 1;
         if(ii = 359) then
         ii <=0;
         ii_gate <= '1';
         end if;

     if ii_gate = '1' then     
     s1 <= sine2(iii);
     iii <= iii+ 1;
     if(iii = 359) then
     iii <= 0;
     end if;

    s2 <= sine2(jj);
    jj <= jj+ 1;
    if(jj = 359) then
    jj <= 0;
    end if;
     s3 <= sine2(kk);
     kk <= kk+ 1;
     if(kk = 359) then
     kk <= 0;
     end if;
     s4 <= sine2(ll);
     ll <= ll+ 1;
     if(ll = 359) then
     ll <= 0;
     end if;

     end if;

end if;

end process;



end Behavioral;
```

2nd code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity digi_clk is
port (clk1 : in std_logic;
      seconds : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
      minutes : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
      hours : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
     );
end digi_clk;

architecture Behavioral of digi_clk is
signal sec,min,hour : integer range 0 to 60 :=0;
signal counta : integer :=1;
signal clka : std_logic :='0';
begin
seconds <= conv_std_logic_vector(sec,6);
minutes <= conv_std_logic_vector(min,6);
hours <= conv_std_logic_vector(hour,5);

 --clk generation.For 100 MHz clock this generates 1 Hz clock.
process(clk1)
begin
if(clk1'event and clk1='1') then
counta <=counta+1;
if(counta = 5) then
clka <= not clka;
counta <=1;
end if;
end if;
end process;

process(clka)   --period of clk is 1 second.
begin

if(clka'event and clka='1') then
sec <= sec+ 1;
if(sec = 59) then
sec<=0;
min <= min + 1;
if(min = 59) then
hour <= hour + 1;
min <= 0;
if(hour = 23) then
hour <= 0;
end if;
end if;
end if;
end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

3rd code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Unsigned.ALL;


Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;


entity freq_div is
    Port (clk_p, clk_n , rst, up, pause : in  STD_LOGIC;
           count : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0));
end freq_div;

architecture Behavioral of freq_div is

signal clk2: std_logic;
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal clk: std_logic_vector(28 downto 0):=(others=>'0');


COMPONENT ila_1

PORT (  clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    probe0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT  ;

 begin

   IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
  generic map (
     DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
     IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
  port map (
     O => clk2,  -- Buffer output
     I => clk_p,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
     IB => clk_n -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
  );



    process(clk2, rst)
        begin
            if (rst = '1')then
                clk <= (others=>'0');
            elsif (clk2'event and clk2 = '1')then
                clk <= clk + 1;
            end if;
    end process;


    process(clk(25), rst,up,pause) 
        begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            cnt <= (others=>'0');
        elsif (clk(25) = '1' and clk(25)'event) then
            if (up = '1' and pause = '0')then
                cnt <= cnt + '1';
            elsif (up = '0' and pause = '0') then
                cnt <= cnt - '1';
            elsif( pause ='1')then
                cnt <= cnt;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    count <= cnt;


    U1 : ila_1   PORT MAP (   clk => clk2 ,      probe0 => cnt    );



end Behavioral;
```

[image: errors obtained]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with self-answering. But you don't need a monster code dump to illustrate that  mixing standard and non-standard libraries is a bad idea. Especially since the answer doesn't explain why, or tell which library to use. You could greatly improve both question and answer, but this has been covered many times before.

Answer (score -1):

IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Arith.ALL and IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL cannot be used together.